# Increase request size limit in aws beanstalk for .net core api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a **.Net core api** installed on **AWS Beanstalk**. I am getting error "client intended to send too large body: 10181136 bytes" on uploading large file. How to increase max request size.

I tried creating ngnix.config file under .ebextensions folder with below configuration

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 50M;
```

it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A likely reason why it does not work for you is that the `nginx` setting you are trying to use (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`) is for the older EB platforms based on  **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1).

But .NET Core platform is based on **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) as listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.dotnetlinux). In this case, you should be using different files for customizing nginx. For AL2, the nginx settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you could try creating the following file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this in visual studio I created a folder .platform and subfolder nginx and further sub folder conf.d . I  then added a myconfig.conf file with client_max_body_size 50M and published it to beanstalk. I didn't work. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal Hi is the `.platform` folder in the root of your application folder?

Comment: I have a solution folder with four projects . I added it in start up project. Should I add it in main solution folder? Will .platform be a solution folder?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal It should be in the root of your zip package. I don't know how exactly you've organized your deployment package, thus its difficult to say more.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I needed to set property "Copy to output directory": always  on myconfig.conf

Comment: @jaspreetchahal No problem. Glad to hear it worked out:-)